# How to create a parallel feed adapters that collects data at once?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I want to create an integration flow which pull data from multiple rss sources
using multiples feed adapters and then save data to a file. All these rss adapters will trigger at
7 am and fetch feeds. These pulls should be in parallel, i mean all the feeds should be pulled at once, not one after another like sequentially. How can i achieve that?

link to GH issue [issue 3677](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3677)

Answer (score 0):

One `FeedEntryMessageSource` can only take feeds from one URL, so for multiple RSS resources you have to configure several `FeedEntryMessageSource` for their own Inbound Channel Adapters.

> will trigger at 7 am

This is about a cron trigger.

See poller configuration `@InboundChannelAdapter.poller`:

```
/**
 * @return The cron expression to create the
 * {@link org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger}. Can be specified as
 * 'property placeholder', e.g. {@code ${poller.cron}}.
 */
String cron() default "";
```

However all these channel adapters are going to share the same `TaskScheduler`.
See docs about its configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler.

It is not true that they are going to be executed sequentially, if there are enough threads in the pool for that `TaskScheduler`.

It might be true if you use the latest Spring Boot, which provides a `TaskScheduler` only with one thread: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.spring-integration

That's it. Nothing more you have to do in your project: if you don't do any async shifting after feed channel adapters, all the downstream flow logic is going to be performed on that scheduled thread.